# Why React Import Couldn't find default.min.css file?

Tags: reactjs, import, module, sass, gulp

I following the React JS Tutorial for Beginner - Build a website using React, Sass, Gulp and Node.js.

I followed all the steps and run gulp from the terminal and it renders a min version of CSS file in the default.min.css

It seems working just fine but the checking in the browser it says:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './Assets/css/default.min.css' in '/Users/qiangbarejie/Desktop/react/reactTutorial/my-react-project/src'
```

Anybody has any idea? Please let me know, thanks!!!

Comment: Can you post the rest of your App.js?

Comment: Does `./Assets/css/default.min.css` actually exist in `/Users/qiangbarejie/Desktop/react/reactTutorial/my-react-project/src`?

Comment: Yes. I copied and pasted the path:     /Users/qiangbarejie/desktop/react/reactTutorial/my-react-project/src/Assets/css
qiangbarejie$ ls
default.min .css

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I double checked the path carefully and found out I made a careless typo. I put an extra space in my default.min.css file name. Now it's working again!!! Thanks.